# SP2013. I edited the HTML master page. It changes on IE but not on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, custom-masterpage

I've been struggling for days now. I edited a custom Master Page html file, the Javascript part. When I browse using IE, the changes are there. On Firefox and Chrome, it is not. On some PCs the changes are not there at all on all browsers. On some other PCs there are changes but only on IE. I already tried delete cache on every browsers. Still not working. Also, the html master page is not visible in the Sharepoint designer. So I had to open explorer to edit it.

I tried copying seattle master page. Then copy pasted the custom master page into the new seattle copy and rename it to something else, linked it to homepage.aspx. But that gives me 'Something went wrong' error.

Comment: Are you using a publishing site? If you are using Publishing site incense check it in and publish your master page HTML file and make sure you are opening the site with same credentials in all browsers.

Comment: Yep I am using publishing site. And using the same credentials in every browsers. The javascript is still aren't the same in all browsers. It is as if there is a script or something detecting the browser and when it doesn't hit what it wants, it uses the default master page. But I can't find what it is. I found the link to the custom master page within '<%@' tag in homepage.aspx file and the link is correct.

Comment: sorry, I can't get you, There have scripts to detect the browser, but why we need to detect the browser, Your Issue is the custom master page is not applied for specific browser right?

Comment: Yes. I checked my edited custom master page again just now. And now the javascript are not applying even to IE browsers. It went back to original custom master page (with no javascript edits). I didn't change a thing except pressing the green refresh button on the sharepoint 2013 designer. Is this some sort of fallback..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have not published the master page. To publish your page, go to Site Settings –> Master pages and page layouts and then find your HTML file.  Hit the publish button on the ribbon.

Reference: [Creating Master Page](http://blog.navantis.com/creating-a-new-master-page-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: Tried publishing as suggested. Does not work.

Comment: Sorry, comment is not clear. Can we say that it was not published earlier. Now that you have published it, it is still not working? if so, has it been approved as well. After publishing, it remains in pending state. Please confirm.

Comment: The page was published and approved and still not working. I am using highest privilege user by the way. Thanks.

Comment: is it possible to share screen?

Comment: Just for confirmation, is it possible that device channels are enabled on site?

Comment: The device channels use default. I tried pointing default to the custom master page under Look and Feel>Master Page. Still no luck.

Comment: Turns out it isn't the browsers. When I visit the page as anonymous user the changes are not there but when I logged in, it is there. Knowing this, I able to search the answer on Google why it is so. I had to check out the master page ( and perhaps edit and save, perhaps not) and then check it in. But checking in doesn't work on my SPD2013 ( no idea why ), so I had to check it in on Site Settings > Master pages. Then the changes are applied to anonymous users as well. I am marking yours as answer. Thanks.